# C# Bitmap Class on Mono Has Invalid Properties

Tags: c#, mono, .net-3.5, openxml

I am using `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class from `System.Drawing` library using NET 3.5.

Code is this:

```
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(filename);
Console.WriteLine("bm.width: " + bm.width); // RETURNS 233, RIGHT AMOUNT
Console.WriteLine("bm.HorizontalResolution: " + bm.HorizontalResolution); // RETURNS 0!!
```

Does anyone have a different compatible class I could use, or any tricks for mono to make this work? I need the resolution to scale images properly in Word (I'm generating .docx files).

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
```

`System.Drawing.Image` has the same behavior.

Comment: Are you sure the image has DPI info in it?

Comment: @fog, is that not a given? Windows finds it not only in C#, but by right clicking it too. It is a normal jpg. I assumed image data is not OS specific.

Comment: It is not. I was just asking because sometimes files don't have embedded DPI data. You can try "file your_file.jpg" from the command line to extract some information and check.

Comment: I imagine this was caused by the following bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33310

Answer (score 5):

It seems that System.Drawing.Graphics returns "proper" Dpi information on Linux environment.

```
var imgPhoto = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imgAbsolutePath); // object with HorizontalResolution and VerticalResolution that return 0 on Linux
var gImage = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(imgPhoto); 
var dpiX = gImage.DpiX;
var dpiY = gImage.DpiY;
```

At least, this is still a problem on .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: little update: it still is a problem in .net5.0 (and your solution still works)

Comment: `System.Drawing.Common` is not supported on non-Windows platforms. See https://aka.ms/systemdrawingnonwindows for more information.